# How to scroll through post thumbnails?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I have two custom post types that each have a post thumbnail. On my homepage, I have a section that I want to display the post thumbnail of each of the custom post types (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtHvp.jpg). I would also like to allow users to scroll through each image by clicking on a "next" or "previous" button. If I use next_post_link(); the link will open up the next post's actual post page but I need it to only show the next posts post thumbnail. Here is my loop:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'post_type' => array( 'client', 'graduate' ) ));
if ( $query->have_posts() )
{
    while ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        $query->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        } 
        ?>
        <h2 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else
{
    // show 404 error here
}
```

Comment: This sounds like you are talking about a Javascript slider. Is that what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah that would actually work. I guess I was just more curious if it could be accomplished by modifying the actual loop or using a WordPress specific function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time right now to address this specifically but [paginating secondary Loops is tricky](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+secondary). I would suggest you [look into `paginate_links`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A21376+paginate_links).